# How to break the rows containing </s>), </s> the string pattern from a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, regex

Assume we have a data frame in Python Pandas that looks like this:

```
          TEXT               Number    
         ((<s>, <s>), ABC)   0.161681
         ((<s>, ABC), DEF)   0.472973
         ((ABC, DEF), DEF)   0.131635
         ((DEF, DEF), DEF)   0.166667
         ((DEF, DEF), DEF)   0.976190
         ((DEF, DEF), XYZ)   0.150969
        ((DEF, XYZ), </s>)   0.092511
       ((XYZ, </s>), </s>)   1.000000
         ((<s>, <s>), ABC)   0.161681
         ((<s>, ABC), GHI)  0.472973
         ((ABC, GHI), GHI)  0.131635
         ((DEF, GHI), GHI)  0.166667
         ((DEF, GHI), GHI)  0.976190
         ((GHI, GHI), XYZ)  0.150969
        ((GHI, XYZ), </s>)  0.092511
       ((XYZ, </s>), </s>)  1.000000
         ((<s>, <s>), ABC)  0.161681
         ((<s>, ABC), JKL)  0.472973
         ((ABC, JKL), JKL)  0.131635
         ((JKL, JKL), JKL)  0.166667
         ((JKL, JKL), JKL)  0.976190
         ((JKL, JKL), XYZ)  0.150969
        ((JKL, XYZ), </s>)  0.092511
       ((XYZ, </s>), </s>)  1.000000
```

How do I break the rows which ends ((XYZ "<"/s">, <"/s">") the the string pattern and store another variable For example, the output should be:

```
((<s>, <s>), ABC)    0.161681
((<s>, ABC), DEF)    0.472973
((ABC, DEF), DEF)    0.131635
((DEF, DEF), DEF)    0.166667
((DEF, DEF), DEF)    0.976190
((DEF, DEF), XYZ)    0.150969
((DEF, XYZ), </s>)   0.092511
((XYZ, </s>), </s>)   0.11111

((<s>, <s>), ABC)    0.161681
((<s>, ABC), GHI)    0.472973
((ABC, GHI), GHI)    0.131635
((DEF, GHI), GHI)    0.166667
((DEF, GHI), GHI)    0.976190
((GHI, GHI), XYZ)    0.150969
((GHI, XYZ), </s>)   0.092511
((XYZ, </s>), </s>)  0.112586


((<s>, <s>), ABC)     0.161681
((<s>, ABC), JKL)     0.472973
((ABC, JKL), JKL)     0.131635
((JKL, JKL), JKL)     0.166667
((JKL, JKL), JKL)     0.976190
((JKL, JKL), XYZ)     0.150969
((JKL, XYZ), </s>)    0.092511
((XYZ, </s>), </s>)   1.000000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of just getting that row info where
capture group 1 contains the *Text* field,
capture group 2 contains the *number* field.

With that info, you can do anything you want.
Replace with your formatting data, for example:
`$1  $2\r\n\r\n` , etc...

`(?m)^[^\S\r\n]*(\([^\S\r\n]*\([^\S\r\n]*[A-Z]+[^\S\r\n]*,[^\S\r\n]*</s>[^\S\r\n]*\)[^\S\r\n]*,[^\S\r\n]*</s>\))[^\S\r\n]+((?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+))[^\S\r\n]*\s*`

Readable version

```
 (?m)                                      # Multi-line mode
 ^                                         # BOL
 [^\S\r\n]*                                # Horizontal whitespace trim

 (                                         # (1 start), Text
      \( [^\S\r\n]* 
      \( [^\S\r\n]* 
      [A-Z]+ 
      [^\S\r\n]* , [^\S\r\n]* 
      </s> [^\S\r\n]* 
      \)
      [^\S\r\n]* , [^\S\r\n]* 
      </s> 
      \)
 )                                         # (1 end)
 [^\S\r\n]+                                # Horizontal whitespace trim, and required separator
 (                                         # (2 start), Number
      (?:
           \d+ 
           (?: \. \d* )?
        |  \. \d+ 
      )
 )                                         # (2 end)
 [^\S\r\n]*                                # Horizontal whitespace trim
 \s*                                       # Whitespace trim (include newlines)
```